# See any changes from contentEditable Angular

Tags: html, angular

I've got a basic table being created where the user can edit a name and it'll log any changes. I've currently got this:

```
<td [attr.contenteditable]="true" #name (input)=name = name.innerText">
   {{name}}
</td>
<button (click)="save(name)">Save</button>
```

TS:

```
name = "Enter Name"

save(name: String){
    console.log(name)
}
```

I've noticed with the innerText portion I'm able to properly track the changes, however, it's only allowing one character to be deleted at a time. Once a character is deleted, it stays in focus but needs to be reclicked to delete another one. Is there a way to prevent this so they can just hit delete once?

Answer (score 0):

I created temporary variables in the TS file to hold any changes, and in the html added
`ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="value" #ctrl="ngModel"` into the td